# Storing Image using query

Tags: android, sql

im trying to store images using query in sql lite. My query didnt work out. here it is:

```
 INSERT INTO shops(image)
 SELECT * FROM
 OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\drawable\hgmall.PNG', SINGLE_BLOB) as image
```

the field type for image is a blob at the moment. I certainly seek your advice.
Do note that my shops table do have other 4 columns with data already inserted

i also like to retrieve it in android IDE. Any one has any suggestions?

Comment: Do you really think **it's a good idea to store images in a db**?! so to grow it fatter and fatter?

Comment: oh because its an assignment. i tried many tutorials i couldnt understand some

Comment: Wouldn't it be **much better** (ask your teacher!) to store just the **image paths as strings**?! You can then retrieve your images from their original locations, without having to **bloat your db** to ridiculously huge sizes.

Comment: Its a year long project and teachers here usually want u to do the research. do u have any code exmaple? or link to refer me to

Comment: a link... a Google search will show you a million and one links. Most of which will point you some posts here on SO.

Comment: ill give it a go. I tried but its hard trying to understand when i started android not long and sql

Comment: But this has nothing to do with Android or SQL. It's just logic. Try to think as Mr. Spock does. ;)